# Spring Boot, Websockets cannot obtain user (i.e, java.security.Principal) from Session

Tags: java, session, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Working with `Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE` and `Spring Websockets`.  Having a deployment runtime issue where when running embedded `Jetty 9`, I cannot fake a user (`java.security.Principal`) successfully when app deployed anywhere else but localhost.

I have consulted

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-runtime-configuration

The config below (I believe) already "upgrades" a request

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    // see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay
    // requires an external broker like AMQP or RabbitMQ
    //registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/");

    // XXX This might wind up being the impl we actually deploy; but be aware it has certain constraints
    // see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-message-flow
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/cards").setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandler()).withSockJS();
}

// cheat; ensure that we have a Principal w/o relying on authentication
class UserHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {

    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                    Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        return new TestPrincipal("bogus");
    }
}
```

And here's the principal...

```
public class TestPrincipal  implements Principal {

private final String name;


public TestPrincipal(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

}
```

But this is the exception I'm receiving...

```
Logger=org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler Type=ERROR Message=Unhandled exception
org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.MissingSessionUserException: No "user" header in message
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver.java:42) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:127) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:451) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:443) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:82) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:412) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:350) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135) [spring-messaging-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

What else should I consider here?

**UPDATE**

I can reproduce this reliably in a localhost deployment now.

Interestingly, using `STS 3.6.3` in debug mode, when I set a breakpoint at line 91 of `JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy`

```
public JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(WebSocketServerFactory factory) {
    Assert.notNull(factory, "WebSocketServerFactory must not be null");
    this.factory = factory;
    this.factory.setCreator(new WebSocketCreator() {
        @Override
        public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest request, ServletUpgradeResponse response) {
            // Cast to avoid infinite recursion
            return createWebSocket((UpgradeRequest) request, (UpgradeResponse) response);
        }
```

Then continue on to another breakpoint set at line 41 of `PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver`

```
@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    Principal user = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getUser(message.getHeaders());
    if (user == null) {
        throw new MissingSessionUserException(message);
    }
    return user;
}
```

the `user` is `null`.  Is there a race condition?  E.g., is there some time limit within which the socket must acquire the user from request?

Comment: I'm using Chrome for browser testing.  Exception manifests client-side as a "Websocket is closed before a connection is established" in console log.  Reaching, but does this: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/94 have something to do w/ it? How am I able to set an alternate port both on client and server sides?

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.0.0.RELEASE/samples/websocket.  Will refactor and report back on whether or not I was successful.

Comment: is your issue solved

Comment: I am also having the same issue were able to solve this issue .